Check if Barcode Scanner is successfully connected to Serial Port
I am currently working on a solution that reads data from a Barcode Scanner through a serial port on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
Is there a way for me to check in my software(Golang) that the Scanner is correctly connected, and data is properly transferred through the port?
I am currently just checking if a scan comes through the port or not after a certain amount of time. Unfortunately this does not tell the user what exactly is desired, as I would like to be able to actively check the connection, independent of the scanner actually scanning anything.
EDIT: I am using a Honeywell 1911i Scanner using RS232(though planning to support other scanners), and reading from the serial port using this library: https://github.com/bugst/go-serial.

What protocol, scanner or lib do you use?

@VincentMenzel edited post with the information.

A modem control signal could be used as an indicator of something connected to the serial port. But the only accurate indication of "correctly connected and data is properly transferred" requires an actual request&response message exchange between host and the device. An inquiry request message that returns a known response message is the ideal exchange.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

One way to do this could be to require the user scans a barcode on the screen to confirm that the scanner is properly connected.
If the scanner is connected via USB, you could check for a connected device matching the same Vendor ID and Product ID of the scanner.  There may be other details too, such as a serial number, which you can check.
